# Im trying to use BleManager but when i declare a instance of BleManager, " TypeError: Cannot read property 'createClient' of null, js engine: hermes "

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im doing a project using React Native, and i trying to use the library react-native-ble-plx, and when i declare a instance of the BleManager, i receive the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'createClient' of null, js engine: hermes", can anyone help me?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { View, Text, LogBox, Easing, Empty } from 'react-native'

import base64 from 'react-native-base64';
import { BleManager } from 'react-native-ble-plx';

const manager = new BleManager()


const EspConnection = ({navigation}) => {



    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Salve vei</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export {EspConnection}
```

its just thay my code, and i can't declare the BleManager

I tried to list all bluetooth conections in my mobile device to connect with them to send data
but i can't even declare the BleManager class